# Unable to open app in play console for testing

Tags: android, google-play-console

I am invited to test an app(url sent) and I get the following error:

"A testing version of this app hasn't been published yet or isn't available for this account."

I am sure that I am logged into the correct account. Tried this from both browser and phone, both dont seem to work. Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

There is one process before testing an application sent from invited url.

**Uninstall** previous application and **Install** application from Invited Link or Play Store.

You have to be **Beta Tester** for an Application

1. Scroll to the bottom of the Application page in PlayStore until you see the section titled Become a beta tester.
2. Tap the I’M IN button, then tap JOIN.
   Wait 10-15 minutes for the beta sign-up process to complete, then return to the app detail page in the Google Play Store.
3. You should see a message saying You’re a beta tester.

Then Please check app again, Above error should be resolved.